# Toggle just works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to use toggle with jQuery and it's working but just once. If I click on the div again the toggle doesn't work, and I have to refresh de page. And if I try on JSFiddle it works fine, I can´t see my mistake.

```js
$("#search_icon").click(function() {
  $("#search").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/magnifying-glass32.png" height="30px" class="social_icons" id="search_icon" />
<div id="pesquisa">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar..." id="search" border="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: There may be JS conflicts or errors. What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Yeah...looking at the code it seems to be working. Any change you included the same script twice or something?

Comment: In the browser it works just fine, click once to show div, click again to hide div. But when I click the 3rd time it doesn't show the div again.
I think there are no conflicts in JS, the id #search and #search_icon are being used just in this function.